# Using shell aliases for compilers or full path name in makefile?

Tags: makefile, alias

When making a makefile, do shell aliases work, and if so, is it frowned upon and we should instead just use the directory name to the aliased path?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "aliases".  Do you mean, `make` variables?  Those are perfectly reasonable and encouraged.  There's no such thing as "aliases" in make.  Maybe if you provided an example we would know what you were thinking of.

Comment: @MadScientist Sorry, I meant shell aliases. e.g., in shell, I might have an alias for g++ 17

Comment: You can't use shell aliases in a makefile... make is not the shell and make doesn't have aliases, or know anything about aliases.